# auto fill row data to match

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

I'm trying to create a Job tracking sheet that has the Client data (address, phone number, etc) automatically appear when the user enters the correlating Site ID in one column.

Here's my example:

- `Main` sheet is where jobs are tracked.
- `MasterSheet` is where the all the master data are.
- Main Sheet Column A is Job ID -- This is manually added by the user.
- Main Sheet Column B is Site ID -- This is manually entered by the user.
- Main Sheet Column C -- This is the column I'd like to auto-fill with the correlating data from MasterSheet based on the Site ID entered in Column B.

Checking around gave me this formula:

```
=if (B1 = "X", vlookup (A1, master-list-data-range, 3, 0  ), "")
```

Obviously that only works if the Site ID on Master List is just plain "X" for all the rows I want to auto fill.

I don't know what formula I can use in order to tell Main Sheet Columns C to:

- Auto fill with information from MasterSheet Column E IF Main Sheet Column B Site ID MATCHES MasterSheet Column B Site ID

Is there a formula I can use for that? I know it's probably some combination of `If` and `VLOOKUP`, but I'm not sure of the exact format.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `=if (B1 <> "", IFERROR(vlookup (B1, master-list-data-range, 3, FALSE ),"??"), "")`

Comment: Hiya Tim! Thanks for your help, but when I use this formula, it keeps returning "??" as a result when it should be displaying data. I'm thinking that it's pulling errors because of the "iferror" statement.

Comment: If there's no match for the value in B1 in the first column of `master-list-data-range` then vlookup will fail and you'll get "??".  Are you sure there's a match?